# Are attack rolls, made by enemy creatures, made behind a screen in Adventurers League?

Tags: dnd-5e, dnd-adventurers-league, attack-roll

Are attack rolls, made by enemy creatures, made behind a screen in Adventurers League? Is it at DM's discretion?

The answer would be useful in order to evaluate the usefulness of the feat Lucky.

Comment: Did you try reading through the Adventurers League rules before asking this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## There is no specification in the Adventurers League rules so it would be DMs discretion.

I've looked through all of the FAQs and guides. No details specifying. Lucky is still a powerful feat for what it gives you.

Note: A dungeon master's screen is listed in the optional items in the [DDAL Dungeon Master's Guide](http://www.dmsguild.com/product/208179/DD-Adventurers-League-DM-Pack).

> **Dungeon Master Screen.** Helpful to hide the
>   adventure and your notes and schemes from the players.

Comment: "Lucky is still mathematically the best all around feat" I feel like this statement though not really part of your argument really needs some form of support.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose I'll remove it. I did the math on effectiveness of feats a bit ago and it's a lot.

Comment: I'm not saying it was wrong, just that it seemed like a bold statement with no support. If you have that math anywhere I'm always down to look at a good spreadsheet. (not for this question, just in general).

Comment: DM guide says it is at the DMs discretion. But when I DM, the non-boss combat I control behind the screen so I can fudge the rolls to keep the game moving forward smoothly and to keep it interesting, but I do publicly viewable rolls for the Big Boss battles. It is important that you make this known day 1 so it wont be questioned later.